# Unrandom back answers using view

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, view

I have created 2 tables which are table questions and answers. i also created view to join the two tables.

```
create table questions(QuestionID int, QuestionText varchar (500));
insert questions
values
(1,          'Question1'),
(2,          'Question2'),
(3,          'Question3');

create table answers(answerID int, answer_question_id int, answertxt varchar(500), 
answer_isright bit);  
insert answers
values
(1, 1, 'answer1', 1),
(2, 1, 'answer2', 0),
(3, 1, 'answer3', 0),
(4, 2, 'answer1', 1),
(5, 2, 'answer2', 0),
(6, 2, 'answer3', 0);
```

view:

```
SELECT questionText, [1], [2], [3]
FROM
(
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionID ORDER BY newid())      
    AnswerInQuestionID,
            answerTxt, 
    QuestionText
FROM questions q
    JOIN answers a
        ON q.QuestionID=a.answer_question_id
) A
PIVOT
(
MAX(answerTxt)
FOR AnswerInQuestionID IN ([1], [2], [3] )
 ) as piv
```

The view is now randomize the answers. How to unrandom back the answers by using view? 
Im using [sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a1739/1) for the demo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT questionText, [1], [2], [3]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY QuestionID ORDER BY answerID) AnswerInQuestionID,
        answerTxt, 
        QuestionText
    FROM questions q
        JOIN answers a
            ON q.QuestionID=a.answer_question_id
) A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(answerTxt)
    FOR AnswerInQuestionID IN ([1], [2], [3] )
) as piv
```

view [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/534af/11)
just change newid() to answerID